# Same server with different Website names

Tags: url, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have given two different different websites names with same IP(192.168.1.142)
Now i am using both these for configuring the reverse proxy using nginx.
Is it ok whether i can run ?
Kindly suggest any problems if any that i might face in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is fine. Use different server {} blocks and the server_name option to specify which configuration is which:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name domain.com;

   # rest of domain.com options go here
}

server {
   # this will be the default site on this host
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name other.com;

   # rest of other.com options go here
}
```

In practice, splitting the two server {} blocks into different files would make maintenance easier and is often the norm.

If you only want the sites to be available on that one IP, change the listen directive to:

```
listen 192.168.1.142:80;
```

Also if you want to use SSL/HTTPS then you may run into complications as you can only have one SSL certificate per IP address. There are solutions if this is the case.